# Group by con Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un problema. Estoy sacando los pedidos de una base de datos, los pedidos pueden tener más de una fila entonces los agrupo por una columna que se llama `ticket`.

Muestro la consulta:

```
$pedidos = DB::table('orders')
           ->join('users', 'orders.id_cliente', '=', 'users.id')
           ->select('orders.ticket', DB::raw('SUM(orders.subtotal + orders.iva + orders.envio) as total'),  'orders.estado', 'orders.metodo', 'orders.created_at', 'orders.factura', 'orders.id_cliente', 'users.name', 'users.apellidos', "users.slug", "users.tipo_id")
           ->selectRaw("GROUP_CONCAT(orders.producto SEPARATOR ', ') AS Productos ")
           ->groupBy('orders.ticket', 'orders.estado', 'orders.metodo', 'orders.created_at', 'orders.factura', 'orders.id_cliente', 'users.name', 'users.apellidos', "users.slug", "users.tipo_id")
           ->get();
```

La cuestión es que hasta ahora funcionaba bien, realizaba un pedido con dos o tres productos(filas) y me lo hacia bien, pero hoy un cliente hizo un pedido con 5 productos y me lo saca en dos filas la agrupación, tres productos en una y dos en otra.

Tampoco entiendo muy bien por que tengo que agrupar por cada campo que quiero mostrar en la vista, hay otra forma de hacer esto, gracias!

Quitando en campo `orders.created_at` si parece que me lo hace bien, pero no se si me encontrare el mismo problema si piden por ejemplo 8 productos, además necesito mostrar la fecha del pedido.

Comment: ¿Alguno de los campos del `GROUP BY` es la clave primaria de `orders`?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia , no ninguno es la primaria

Comment: Entonces tienes un problema de diseño de la tabla. Parece que hay múltiples campos dependientes en `GROUP BY` que has separado en otra tabla. ¿Estás seguro que la culpa no es porque alguno de ellos cambia para un mismo ticket?

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia si correcto, el fallo esta que el created_at sale en un segundo diferente. Hay forma de solucionarlo sin necesidad de cambiar las tablas?